# Unity and C# click/touch over specific UI element check

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a code where if I start click or touch the screen and drag for specific distance does something. I would like to check whenever it is over a specific area (lets say over UI like canvas). **The main goal is to have the upper half of the screen to react on click and touch.**

I tried to do so by creating new Rect. This works, but I can`t make the rect on upper part of the screen (right now it is on the lower part of the screen). I might be missing something, but the following code should create rect in the upper part of the screen, not ?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && bounds.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
        {
            Debug.Log("Touchableee!");
            TouchableArea = true;
        }

        if (TouchableArea == true)
        {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
            TouchableArea = false;
        }

    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isDraging = false;
        Reset();
    }
```

Any ideas are welcome, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting the Rect at the bottom of the screen, thus why it's on the bottom half.

> Parameters
>
> > x The X value the rect is measured from.
> >
> > y The Y value the rect is measured from.
> >
> > width The width of the rectangle.
> >
> > height    The height of the rectangle.

The following should work for you:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect(0, Screen.height, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width);
```